# Delete element on click of its delete button in editText span

Tags: android

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
TextView tv = createContactTextView(contactName);
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(tv);
bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(),bd.getIntrinsicHeight());

sb.append(contactName + ",");
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length()-(contactName.length()+1), sb.length()-            1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
to_input.setText(sb);

public static Object convertViewToDrawable(View view) {
  int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  view.measure(spec, spec);
  view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
  c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
  view.draw(c);
  view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap cacheBmp = view.getDrawingCache();
  Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
  view.destroyDrawingCache();
  return new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);

}

public TextView createContactTextView(String text){
  //creating textview dynamically
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText(text);
  tv.setTextSize(20);
  tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval);
  tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,     R.drawable.ic_clear_search_api_holo_light, 0);
 tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              Drawable co =  ((TextView) v).getCompoundDrawables()[2];

                if (event.getX() > v.getMeasuredWidth() - v.getPaddingRight()
                        - co.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
                            //tv.setText("");
                            Log.i(TAG, "clicked on delete button");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        }

});
  return tv;


}
```

It will create Spans with text inside editText But I want to delete span On click of delete button in that span . I wrote code for it    "tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {................" in createContactTextView function but its not working.
    [image]}

Comment: I am looking for the same...Please share the code if you have found the solution...

Comment: Of course it does not. The Text View is not used directly. The TextView has got a OnTouchListener, but after only a bitmap of the text view is displayed, there is no more EventListner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ImageSpan and ClickableSpan to same start and end locations.

```
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd),startSpan ,endSpan , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                       //  DeleteHere
                    }
                }, startSpan , endSpan , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Also remove your touchlistener, it won't work! Now set LinkMovement to your edittext.

```
editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```